# How can I enable Full-Text indexing using SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I did it using the commands as described [here](http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/full-text-search.html) and it works but **I want to do it using the SQL Management Studio**.

SQL Server 2008 Books Online says this:

> To create a full-text catalog:
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, expand the server,
>      expand **Databases**, and expand the
>      database in which you want to create
>      the full-text catalog.
> 2. Expand 
>      **Storage**, and then right-click
>      Full Text Catalogs.
>
> Select **New Full-Text Catalog**.
>
> In the New **Full-Text Catalog** dialog
>   box, specify the information for the
>   catalog that you are re-creating. For
>   more information, see New Full-Text
>   Catalog (General Page).
>
> Click **OK**.

There's no such option as Storage in my SQL Server Management Studio.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've got the same problem for my sql 2008 express projects. The catalog is there, installed and all working fine. Just can't access it via the GUI. Have to use T-Sql :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.  It appears that SSMS-E does not support management of FullText catalogs.

There is a free add-in on CodePlex (http://www.codeplex.com/FulltextManager) that appears to add this functionality.

Alternately, you could purchase SQL2008 Developer edition (I believe the cost is still only $49US) which includes the full edition of SSMS, and can connect to a SSE installation.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install **SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services** in order to be able to use Full Text search in 2008 Express.

Comment: I was able to enable Full-Text Search using commands, so it is enabled. But why I can't set it up using the Management studio?

Comment: There is a bug in management studio's UI but you can do it by running commands.

Answer (score 2):

You should install SQL Express 2008 service pack 1 ->
http://www.apijunkie.com/APIJunkie/blog/post/2010/07/12/Fix-SQL-Server-2008-Express-Full-Text-Index-Management-Missing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the full edition of SSMS or the Express edition?

Also, are you using the latest version of the SQL BooksOnline.  either the August 2008 release, or the online version.  The version of BOL that shipped at RTM was unfortunately written primarly around the February release, and there were a significant number of changes to SSMS between then and release.

Comment: I updated the BOL yesterday so it might be up to date. I'm using the Express edition.

Comment: I'm using the full version of Management Studio and can't manage full text search from it. So I guess it's either the tool from Codeplex or TSQL

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Advanced, which does support fulltext search.

Comment: you do know this topic is 3 years old, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I guess using the CodePlex addin is the only way, because even with SSMS from Standard edition you are unable to manage Express fulltext catalogs.